# Create materials with texture from file at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a several .bmp files and path (from XML file) to them. I want theese files to become a materials, but it does not happen.

The code below returns a strange result. All materials has a texture, that looks like a red question symbol on white background.

Please, help me to fix this, or to find a correct way to solve this

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;

    private ImageConverter _Converter = new ImageConverter();

    private Material CreateMaterialWithTexture(string Path)
        {
            if (File.Exists(Path))
            {
                Texture2D _Tx = new Texture2D(16, 16);
                _Tx.LoadImage((byte[])_Converter.ConvertTo(Image.FromFile(Path), typeof(byte[])));
                Material _M = new Material(MaterialPrefab);
                _M.mainTexture = _Tx;
                return _M;
            }
        }
```

Comment: When using Unity, avoid using anything from the `System.Drawing;` namespace. Unity has built in functions to load images from a byte array.

Comment: I've changed my files extentions from ".bmp" to ".png". Both solutions started working. Thanks!